# Pythonic way for magaging and using user-created shared libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

tl;dr I have a directory of common files outside of my various project directories. What is the pythonic way of using/importing these common files inside my projects, and for building them into an output directory.

Background:
I'm in school and taking a data structures class that uses Python as the language. I'm learning the languages as I take the class but have having some issues trying to maintain a shared code base.

In all of the other languages I've used, both compiled and interpreted, there has been a fairly intuitive way of being able to keep shared modules separate from the code that is using them so that updating a shared module doesn't require updates to the calling code.

This is how I initially had my directory structure organized.

```
/.../Projects
    Assignment_1
        __init__.py
        classA.py
        classB.py
    Assignment_2
        __init__.pu
        classC.py
    (etc)
```

After realizing that much of the functionality of classA and classB would be required later on, I reorganized to this:

```
/.../Projects
    Common
        Sorters
            __init__.py
            BubbleSort.py
            MergeSort.py
        __init__.py
        SimpleProfiler.py
    Assignment_1
        __init__.py
        main.py
    Assignment_2
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

My issue is that I can't find a good way of importing things like SimpleProfiler or MergeSort from main,py. Right now I'm manually coping all of the Common files into each assignment, which is bad.

I understand that one possible solution is to update the path to include the common folder form within each main.py file, but I've also read that this is very hacky and isn't encouraged.

Another Stackoverflow answer to a similar question suggested that the user structure everything under one large project. I tried this but still couldn't import modules from one sibling into another sibling.

My other issue is how to package everything together when submitting the assignment. In other languages it was easy to implement a build script that would scan the main project for any imports, then copy (flatten) those imported files into a single output directory which I could then compress and submit for grading. I'm using PyCharm, but can't seem to find a way to reference the imports as part of the build process. Is there any kind of script for this? Whatever the solution is, I need to be able to submit the project in such a way that all the instructor has to do is call a single python file (such as main.py)

This issue isn't unique to a school setting, but seems universal to most programming projects. So, what is the pythonic way of managing a shared code base and for building that shared code into a final project?

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem is. Why can't you do `from Common import SimpleProfiler`?

Comment: (And not related, but Python convection is to use `lower_case_with_underscore` for module names.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because when I run Assignment_1/main.py, I get an error when trying to import anything from Common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I think it is better to use PYTHONPATH environment variable]

I think of two very similar alternatives:

```
/.../Projects
    Common
        Sorters
            __init__.py
            BubbleSort.py
            MergeSort.py
        __init__.py
        SimpleProfiler.py
    assignment_1.py
    assignment_2.py
```

If you use, from `assignment_1.py`, the following import: `from Common.Sorters.BubbleSort import bubble_sort`. This is because, by default, PYTHONPATH considers the current path as a valid PYTHONPATH. This is assuming that you are invoking the scripts `assignment_*` directly.

The other alternative would be:

```
/.../Projects
    Common
        Sorters
            __init__.py
            BubbleSort.py
            MergeSort.py
        __init__.py
        SimpleProfiler.py
    Assignment_1
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    Assignment_2
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
```

And invoking the assignments like so: `python -m Assignment_1` (**from the `Projects` folder**). By default, "executing" a module like that will load its `__main__.py` code. (This is not a rigurous explanation, although [the official one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) is a bit short).

It works for the same reasons as before: Python interpreter will consider the current path as a valid PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work partly. Two questions however. First, is there anyway to tell python to use something other than `__main__.py`, so that I can use the name of the assignment?  Second, this doesn't address the other part of my question, which was a way to somehow flatten or build an output directory that contains all of the imported .py files.

Comment: @BrianHVB No, just like you cannot change the `__init__.py`, you cannot change the `__main__.py`. Common ettiquete is running from there whatever you want, with the appropriate name. About the other question, I would simply put everything (all the common folder) together. Trying to cherry pick modules is error-prone and doesn't feel like any improvement or advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting PYTHONPATH environment variable to your directory. 
Python first searches for files being imported in sys.path, and the first directory in sys.path is the current directory. PYTHONPATH is the next where python will look for files.

Comment: This does seem like the easiest way. One quibble: PyCharm doesn't like me having an import statement following anything, even a setting of the python path. (PEB 8). I can disable the warning but feel kind of guilty about doing so.

Comment: Is there any way to place the path.append statement in a separate location that will automatically be run? I tried it in the `__init__.py` file but this seems to only run if something else loads/imports main.py

Answer (score 0):

On the minimum end, make a PyCharm run configuration that sets your PYTHONPATH before executing and include the other directory. That way you don't need to do a sys.path call in your code.

Closer to the "perfect" end, make your other directory into a Python package with a setup.py. Then, using the interpreter from your project, do "python path/to/other/dir/setup.py develop" to bring your separately-developed package into the consuming project.